# Copy characters from DevExpress XtraRichEdit to a TextBox using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, richtextbox

I have a Winform application with a `DevExpress XtraRichEdit` and a `TextBox` control.

I need to copy the characters in the XtraRichEdit to the TextBox as I go on typing until the space key is pressed.

e.g. I will type in the XtraRichEdit and the typed characters needs to be copied and shown simultaneously in the TextBox.

How to achieve this using c#.

Comment: 1. Using `DataBindings` to bind properties between 2 controls 2. Handle some `TextChanged` event ?

Comment: Can you give some code example? TextChanged event will be easy in case of two TextBoxes instead of one being a XtraRichEdit.

Comment: of course if you let me know whether your `XtraRichEdit` has property `DataBindings` and event `TextChanged`? I don't use `DevEXpress`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your `XtraRichEdit` has `TextChanged` , `Text` and `KeyPress`:

1. Using `DataBindings`:

   ```
   textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", xtraRichEdit1, "Text");
   private void xtraRichEdit1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
      if(e.KeyChar == ' ') textBox1.DataBindings.Remove(textBox1.DataBindings["Text"]);
   }
   ```
2. Using `TextChanged`:

   ```
   bool spacePressed;
   private void xtraRichEdit1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
      if(spacePressed) return;
      textBox1.Text = xtraRichEdit1.Text;
   }
   private void xtraRichEdit1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
      if(e.KeyChar == ' ') spacePressed = true;
   }
   ```
3. Using `KeyPress`:

   ```
   bool spacePressed;
   private void xtraRichEdit1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e){
      if(e.KeyChar == ' ') spacePressed = true;
      if(!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)&&!spacePressed)
         textBox1.AppendText(e.KeyChar.ToString());
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextChanged` event of `XtraRichEdit` control to copy the text to textbox.

Something like- (Not tested)

```
XtraRichEdit1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       textBox2.Text = XtraRichEdit1.Text;
}
```

Comment: XtraRichEdit1.Text gets the whole Text. I need  only the characters from first space entered to the second space  entered